# How do I make a wobbly keyboard key stable again?

Tags: technology

I have a wobbly keyboard key on my old D610, and while the computer is still usable, an arrow key is loose. You have to press it multiple times for it to register. Short of replacing the key, is there a way to make it work again?

Comment: If the key can be popped off easily (a piece of strong thread looped under the key can be used to pull it, or a small L-shaped metal tool), you can see if the plastic surround holding the key in place is damaged. If so, you might build up the broken piece with epoxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I"ve had to do this more times than I would like to remember.  It's very difficult to explain but I did find this as well as a video.  See the bottom.  Good luck to you!

From Laptop-keys.com

How to fix laptop keyboard keys for the Dell Latitude D610

If your Dell laptop key is broken or missing, you have come to the right place for all resources to fix or repair your laptop keyboard key. Rather than spending hundereds of dollars on a new keyboard, you will find that replacement laptop keys is cheaper and easier to do. Here, we will give a quick tutorial on how to replace the laptop key on your Dell Latitude D610. This is a supplimental guide in addition to the video installation instructions above on you to replace your Dell Latitude D610 keyboard key:

Now, to install your new Dell Latitude D610 latop key, begin by orientating the retainer clip in the proper direction of the keyboard. Typically, the small plastic feet on the plastic hinge will be spaced appropriately for you to determine which direction the plastic parts go in relation to the metal hooks on the keyboard base. Observe the laptop key retainer clips carefully and notice that the smoother side will always face up, additionally, the plastic feet on the laptop keyboard key retainer clip will always face downward to allow the hinge to fit into the metal hooks. Once the retainer clip is situated correctly, lock it into the metal hooks on the keyboard base, it is always easier approaching it from one direction and hooking in the plastic clip than another. If one direction does not work, try the other. Now the laptop key retainer clip will be securely attached and ready to accept the plastic key top. If the laptop key is the type with the metal supporting bars, those will need to be inserted into the matching metal hooks as the laptop key cap slides over the plastic retainer clip and before it is pressed on. Once the keyboard key is positioned squarely over the retaining clip, press down gently until you hear a distinct click on all 4 corners. This indicates that the key cap has been secured to the retainer clip correctly. Pull up on all four corners gently to ensure that this happened correctly. That's it! You have successfully completed a repair on an individual key for the Dell Latitude D610 laptop key.

## Here's a video from youtube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?x-yt-cl=84411374&v=i2t40LRgb9A&x-yt-ts=1421828030